# Missing permissions when running through ExecStart

Tags: systemd, shadowsocks

I've set up [shadowsocks-libev](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev) and have been running it with the following systemctl service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks-Libev Manager Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=nobody
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ss-manager -c /etc/shadowsocks/%i.json

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I recently noticed that my shadowsocks config file (`/etc/shadowsocks/manager.json`) had global read permissions, so I changed it to 600 and made sure the owner was `nobody`. For some reason this causes the process to fail to read the configuration file when starting up.

`systemctl start shadowsocks-libev-manager@manager.service`

`ss-manager[1357]:  2018-01-05 11:41:00 ERROR: Invalid config path.`

This is the same error I see as when I revoke all read privileges for that file.

However, it works fine if I start shadowsocks using the exact same command from the command line:

`sudo -u nobody /usr/bin/ss-manager -c /etc/shadowsocks/manager.json`

Similarly, I have no trouble reading the file as `nobody` using `cat` or `less`.

When I check the process started by `systemctl` in `ps` it shows that it's running as `nobody`, and when the process outputs files the owner is set to `nobody`. Why can't it access this file? Why is there a difference between running it through systemctl and running it from the terminal?

My problem seems similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178085/runs-perfectly-through-the-command-line-will-not-work-through-systemd-execstart), but I don't have any quotes in my ExecStart so that solution is not applicable in my case.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/etc/shadowsocks`?

Comment: `/etc/shadowsocks/` has `rwxr-xr-x` permissions.

Comment: I do not have a good idea what could be the problem but you could use this command instead `/usr/bin/strace -o /tmp/nobody.strace -f /usr/bin/ss-manager -c /etc/shadowsocks/manager.json` and have a look at the file `/tmp/nobody.strace` afterwards. That might give you some clue.

Comment: I like the idea, but when I put that in ExecStart I get `/usr/bin/strace: Can't fopen '/tmp/nobody.strace': Permission denied`. Running it directly from the terminal (with `sudo -u nobody`) produces the trace file and behaves as expected. I think the user `nobody` must be restricted in some strange way.

Comment: Maybe it helps to run `strace -p 1 -f` to understand how this process is modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem, which stemmed from something unique to the user `nobody`. I'm still not entirely sure what makes that user unique though.

When run as `nobody` I see the following output in journald:

```
Started Shadowsocks-Libev Manager Service.
ERROR: Invalid config path.
Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is indicative of it being unable to access the config file despite having the necessary permissions.

When run as a different user I newly created (with no home directory) I see the following output in journald instead:

```
Started Shadowsocks-Libev Manager Service.
ERROR: mkdir: No such file or directory
ERROR: unable to create working directory
Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is because it attempts to write to the user's home directory which does not exist.

I then created a new user named `shadowsocks` with its own home directory:

```
# useradd -m -s /usr/bin/nologin shadowsocks
```

Running as this user I encounter no problems.

Comment: I had the same issue. I think the problem is the home dir. The source code shows working dir is hardcoded to home dir: https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/blob/master/src/manager.c#L1134